# how to use netcdf flag_meanings attribute in python

Tags: python, netcdf

I'm creating a netcdf file in python and want to assign 'flag_values' and 'flag_meanings' attributes to one of the variables.  The variable name is 'cs', flag_values should be (0,1) and flag_meanings should be ('STRATIFORM', 'CONVECTIVE').

To make those assignments in python, I've used:

```
cs.flag_values = numpy.array((0,1))
cs.flag_meanings = numpy.array(['STRATIFORM','CONVECTIVE'])
```

The 'flag_values' assignment works fine, but the 'flag_meanings' assignment gives me a concatenated string of the two input values and I can't figure out how I can get the strings to be separate entities.  This is part of the ncdump on the output file:

```
cs:flag_values = 0L, 1L ;
cs:flag_meanings = "STRATIFORMCONVECTIVE" ;
```

When I just try creating an array of strings and printing it, I have no problem:

```
>>> a = np.array(['STRATIFORM','CONVECTIVE'])
>>> print a
['STRATIFORM' 'CONVECTIVE']
```

So what's the secret?

Comment: The underling question is not about writing string arrays, but about how to correctly write the `flag_meanings` attribute. Perhaps modify the title and question to reflect that; this is useful for others having the same question or having a real question about writing string arrays.

Comment: For those who effectively want to write string arrays, do it as `np.array(["stratiform", "convective"], np.str)`, which results in `array(['stratiform', 'convective'], dtype='<U10')`. N.B.: netcdf4-python also accepts `np.str` and `str` as a `Variable` `datatype`, so this is not only for attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [CF-conventions (Section 3.5, “Flags”)](http://cfconventions.org/cf-conventions/v1.6.0/cf-conventions.html#flags), `flag_meanings` is a string in which the meanings are separated by a blank (space):

> The flag_meanings attribute is a string whose value is a blank separated list of descriptive words or phrases, one for each flag value. Each word or phrase should consist of characters from the alphanumeric set and the following five: '_', '-', '.', '+', '@'. If multi-word phrases are used to describe the flag values, then the words within a phrase should be connected with underscores.

So the definition should be

```
cs.flag_meaning = "convective stratiform"
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone.  I think I have it now.

Comment: @Stacy: please vote up useful questions and comments and accept the answer you consider correct. (That is how you thank people on StackOverflow.)

Comment: Sorry.  Didn't know the protocol.  I found the most recent response from equaeghe did the trick.  Thanks.

Comment: @Stacy: That's fine, but please then click the checkmark and up arrow next to my answer.

Comment: Clicked on the checkmark to make it green but when I clicked on the up arrow, it quickly changed the number below if from 0 to 1 and then back to 0.  Not sure what to do about that.

Comment: @Stacy: Ah, you need 15 reputation to be able to do that, it seems. This will come once you ask another good question or give a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the string array only is supported in netCDF4--Are you using the correct module and the correct flags when creating the file. You want to use the netcdf4-python module (https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python) and you need to create the file as:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
nc = Dataset('test.nc', 'w', format='NETCDF4')
```

NETCDF4 should be the default format, but if it's being overridden (or if you're not using a netcdf4 library), I don't think string arrays are supported.

Comment: I am using 'import netCDF4' and creating the netcdf file using the format = 'NETCDF4' parameter, so that's not the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I know it is an old post, but for future reference.

Try,

```
cs.flag_meaning = "Convective, Stratiform"
```

Comment: The meanings should be separated by a blank only, without using the comma. See my answer.